# Is it safe to have your email password in a rails rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

Say I have this in config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "smtp.mysite.com",
  :port                 => 587,
  :domain               => "mysite.com",
  :user_name            => "myuser",
  :password             => "secretpassword",
  :authentication       => "plain",
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}

ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

When I upload my code to, say, Heroku, is it really a good idea to have my password exposed like this? Is there some standard way that's more secure?

Answer (score 2):

Anything you do to access that email account is going to put your email security in the hands of Heroku.  Anything at all that your code can do from their website can also be done by one of their admins or anyone else who manages to read your code.

You'd be far better off sending the email from Heroku so that the authorized email sender would be the user that is running the code.  By handing it a password, you are elevating the access and privileges of anyone who can read that code.  An administrator at Heroku already has more access than your code does, so using the local emailer there doesn't require the exposure of privs that they don't already have.